# I have written a piece of code that does reconciliation: The first part checks between columns:

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a piece of code that does reconciliation:

The first part checks between columns.

Works absolutely fine on upto 100k Rows, then simply freezes on anything bigger. Is the an optimal way to write this? Should I be using a scripting dictionary for the reconciliation too? Ive been off VBA for a while now and I am pretty rusty! Thanks for reading and helping.

```
Sub AutoRecon()
    Worksheets("Main_Recon").Select
    Dim i As Long, _
    LRa As Long, _
    LRb As Long, _
    rowx As Long
    LRa = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    LRb = Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    rowx = 2

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False    

    For i = 2 To LRa
        If Range("A" & i).Errors.Item(xlNumberAsText).Value = True Then
            Range("A" & i).Value = "N" & Range("A" & i).Value
            rowx = rowx + 1
        End If
    Next i


    rowx = 2
    For i = 2 To LRb
        If Range("G" & i).Errors.Item(xlNumberAsText).Value = True Then
            Range("G" & i).Value = "N" & Range("G" & i).Value
            rowx = rowx + 1
        End If
    Next i


    rowx = 2
    For i = 2 To LRa
        If IsError(Application.Match(Range("A" & i).Value, Range("G2:G" & LRb), 0)) Then
            Range("O" & rowx).Value = Range("A" & i).Value
            rowx = rowx + 1
        End If
    Next i

    rowx = 2
    For i = 2 To LRb
        If IsError(Application.Match(Range("G" & i).Value, Range("A2:A" & LRa), 0)) Then
            Range("S" & rowx).Value = Range("G" & i).Value
            rowx = rowx + 1
        End If
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This takes too long.

Answer (score 0):

1. The issue is that you run the loop 4 times, but you can combine 2 loops.
2. You can gain some speed in the process using arrays to read/write. Every read/write action to a cell needs a lot of time. So the idea is to read all data cells into an array `DataA` **at once** (only 1 read action) then process the data in the array and then write it back to the cells at once (only 1 write action). So if you have 100 rows you save 99 read/write actions.

So you would end up with something like below. Note this is untested, so backup before running this.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub AutoRecon()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main_Recon")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'find last rows of columns
    Dim LastRowA As Long
    LastRowA = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim LastRowG As Long
    LastRowG = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row

    'read data into array
    Dim DataA() As Variant 'read data from column A into array
    DataA = ws.Range("A1", "A" & LastRowA).Value
    Dim DataG() As Variant 'read data from column G into array
    DataG = ws.Range("G1", "G" & LastRowG).Value


    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = 2 To Application.Max(LastRowA, LastRowG) 'combine loop to the max of both columns
        If iRow <= LastRowA Then 'run only until max of column A
            If ws.Cells(iRow, "A").Errors.Item(xlNumberAsText).Value = True Then
                DataA(iRow, 1) = "N" & DataA(iRow, 1)
            End If
        End If

        If iRow <= LastRowG Then 'run only until max of column G
            If ws.Cells(iRow, "G").Errors.Item(xlNumberAsText).Value = True Then
                DataG(iRow, 1) = "N" & DataG(iRow, 1)
            End If
        End If
    Next iRow

    'write array back to sheet
    ws.Range("A1", "A" & LastRowA).Value = DataA
    ws.Range("G1", "G" & LastRowG).Value = DataG

    'read data into array
    Dim DataO() As Variant 'read data from column O into array (max size = column A)
    DataO = ws.Range("O1", "O" & LastRowA).Value
    Dim DataS() As Variant 'read data from column G into array (max size = column G)
    DataS = ws.Range("S1", "S" & LastRowG).Value

    Dim oRow As Long, sRow As Long
    oRow = 2 'output row start
    sRow = 2
    For iRow = 2 To Application.Max(LastRowA, LastRowG) 'combine loop to the max of both columns
        If iRow <= LastRowA Then
            If IsError(Application.Match(DataA(iRow, 1), DataG, 0)) Then
                DataO(oRow, 1) = DataA(iRow, 1)
                oRow = oRow + 1
            End If
        End If

        If iRow <= LastRowG Then
            If IsError(Application.Match(DataG(iRow, 1), DataA, 0)) Then
                DataS(sRow, 1) = DataG(iRow, 1)
                sRow = sRow + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next iRow

    'write array back to sheet
    ws.Range("O1", "O" & LastRowA).Value = DataO
    ws.Range("S1", "S" & LastRowG).Value = DataS

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: It says type mismatch at:

If IsError(Application.Match(DataA(iRow, 1), DataG, 0)) Then

Comment: @MithunKumar That's strange I tested it now and it works for me. What is the value of `iRow` and `DataA(iRow, 1)` and `LastRowA` and `LastRowG` in case of error? • Did you change anything in the code?

Comment: I have copied the file here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2m45os3gp1irtct/M2U_RPA.xlsm?dl=0


iRow =2, DataA(iRow, 1) is as in the sheet. It does not begin the loop.

Comment: In this file there is no sheet `Main_Recon` please clarify

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fyhq5w33sugcjl6/5-5Recon.xlsm?dl=0 Sorry that was the wrong link.

Comment: Actually the code runs on your data. But it will need approximately 5 days. The immense number of Matches in the last loop is the problem. You must either reduce your data find another approach or use something else than Excel (that is able to multithread and use more than one CPU core, VBA is single-threaded only!)